# How to export Android Signing Keys

Tags: xamarin

I have two machines, one PC, one Mac.  Both have Xamarin Studio.  On my PC, I've configured an Android Signing Key, and have published an app to Google Play using this key.  I made some app changes to the code - on my Mac - and attempted to sign using a different key and upload, and of course, I got the "you must sign with the same key" error.

I can't find a way to export the Android Signing Key from the Xamarin Studio installation on my PC.  I can see where to import a new key, but not how to export an existing key.  I also checked Certificate Manager for both local system and my user account on Windows, no luck.

Any idea how to export?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my installation every release keystore is stored at X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\AppName
Check also [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/)

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for self generated Keystore path,

Right click on Keystore Name -> Show Alias Info -> at bottom you will see path of self generated Keystore

Comment: /Users/Afzal/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/MobileEpic/MobileEpic.keystore

Comment: Thanks this helped.  For Visual Studio for Mac I went via the following: Right Click Project | View Archives | Resign with a different Key | then right click and select Show Alias Info as @afzal suggested.

Answer (score 6):

To locate the key to export, find the file first in this path:

On Windows (apparently):

```
X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore
```

On macOS:

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/alias/alias.keystore
```

(Note, depending on how you signed the last time, `alias` may be the same as `username`, as it was in my case.)

So I simply copied the keystore file from that location over to the other OS. When importing it in Visual Studio (clicking the "Import..." button in the "Distribute" dialog), it asks you three things:

```
Password:
Alias:
Key password:
```

You cannot leave any field as blank! The password is the key password that you used in macOS to sign. The Alias is the name of the file without the `.keystore` extension, and the "Key password" is the new password that you may want to use for Windows (I left it as the same as in my macOS, myself).